# Docker hangs when trying to delete MongoDB image

Tags: mongodb, docker, containers, docker-image

I am attempting to delete a MongoDB image on my Docker desktop.  But after I click the modal to confirm deletion, it hangs with a message saying "Delete Image?  The 'mongo@latest' image is selected for deletion".  See screenshot below:

[image]

It does not give any error message.  It just hangs on this dialog box interminably.

How do I fix this and delete images effectively?

Comment: Have you tried `docker rmi mongo@latest` in the command line as an alternative? Does that give you an error message?

Answer (score 0):

The issue resolved itself.  After about an hour the deletion completed.

Answer (score 0):

My advice is to try it on the command line.
First check if there are any instance running and stop them

```
docker container list
docker stop <container id>
```

Then try deleting the image:

```
docker images
docker rmi -f <image id>
```

There is no way to know what the GUI is doing, but I suspect it's hanging because there is a container running. The `docker rmi -f` actually force the deletion.